# Resize clojure-lanterna terminal/screen from code

Tags: clojure, lanterna

I'm toying around with clojure-lanterna but haven't found a way to resize the terminal/screen from code. Even in lanterna itself so far I haven't found a way to accomplish this.

I need this functionality because I need a certain size and to put it softly it would be rather ugly to demand that users resize on application start-up.

Does anyone know of a way that I could have missed?

Comment: could you accomplish this with a wrapper script instead? I didn't see anything in Lanterna either.

Comment: What would this wrapper script wrap, exactly?
And how would it help in resizing a Swing CLI window?

Comment: Resizing a Swing window seems more straightforward,  https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/lanterna/terminal/swing/SwingTerminal.java#329 , I was looking at resizing the terminal -- by wrapper script I mean writing a wrapper (in bash for example) that launches the terminal (i.e. not a Swing emulated terminal) in the size you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've talked with one of the Lanterna developers. It turns out that resizing in code isn't (cleanly) possible at this time, but the feature has been added to the wish list for 3.0.